# Have a connection problem with smart Contract using web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, connections

> Anyone that can help me in how to interact with our smartcontract
>   using web3.js.

I tried below code but this not work:
This the code that I am using:

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined')
{
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);} 
else {
                web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("htpp://localhost:8545"));
            }

            web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

            var careercertificateContract = web3.eth.contract(CODE ABI);

        var careercertificate = careercertificateContract.at('0xe1EeCd0a848Bf59509F32f0c97B61d34727C84AB');
        console.log(Certificate);

        $("#button").click(function(){

            Certificate.createCertificate($("#id").val(), $("#fecha").val(), $("#NombreAlumno").val(), $("#RutA").val(), $("#NombreInstitucion").val(), $("#RutI").val(), $("#titulo").val(), $("#FechaTitulacion").val(), $("#NumeroRegistro").val(), $("#CodigoVer").val(), $("#TotalHash").val(),);

        });
```

Comment: Can you add error log that you faced during above code execution?

Comment: Possibly related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78019/unable-to-call-methods-on-my-deployed-contract/78029

Answer (score 0):

Use `careercertificate.createCertificate(params)` instead of `Certificate.createCertificate(params)` because `careercertificate` is the instance that is properly pointing to the contract. And if using `web3js@0.20` then defiantly use callback functions for the response e.g

```
 careercertificate.createCertificate(params, (err, res) => { //es6 
    if(!err) //some logic
})
```

**OR**
If using `web3js1.0.0` then using async/await or `then` e.g

```
careercertificate.createCertificate(params).then(res => {
   //some logic
})
```

Hope it helps!