# Unable to call methods on my deployed contract

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-deployment

Problem: All method calls to my deployed contract return null

Versions:

> Geth: 1.9.9-unstable
>   Git Commit: c2d65d34d5c6f27b8d1a52280964023a3eefd66e
>
> solc:
>   Version: 0.5.13+commit.5b0b510c.Linux.g++
>
> web3: web3@0.20.1

An ERC20 contract takes four arguments in the constructor. My constructor is defined like this:

```
  string public name;
  string public symbol;
  address public admin; // For debugging
  uint8 public decimals;
  uint256 public totalSupply;
  event Deployed(address indexed _admin, uint256 indexed _totalSupply, string _name); // For debugging

  constructor(string memory _tokenName, string memory _tokenSymbol, uint8 _decimals, uint256 _initialSupply) public {
    name = _tokenName;
    symbol = _tokenSymbol;
    decimals = _decimals;
    totalSupply = _initialSupply;

    admin = msg.sender; // For debugging
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;

    emit Deployed(msg.sender, totalSupply, _tokenName); // For debugging
  }
```

I use this JavaScript code to deploy an ERC20 contract to my private test net.

```
var contractObject = web3.eth.contract(<ABI definition>);
var submittedContract = contractObject.new('DKK', 'DKK', 1, 1000000,  {data:'<bin>', gas: 20000000}, <callback>);
```

Calling `eth.getTransactionReceipt(submittedContract.transactionHash);` returns (only relevant fields included):

```
eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xeb512f29ef2789b592b19acbbb78f8c6be6f7eaed96460c239e0a5d8c20e1dd2");
{
  contractAddress: "0xe23cfc0248b83a4bce8f9701a86e08e9cf9c59f4",
  ...
  logs: [{
      ...
      data: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003444b4b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      ...
      topics: ["0xf0bbe877a87290e236ea898bbce0d78d6ac7d54d62e32744b129798a2669e39b", "0x00000000000000000000000075bf9b4280b7963ddb1e9198b3aca5b1e02dcf57", "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f4240"],
      ...
  }],
  status: "0x1",
...
}
```

The `status` field should indicate that there were no errors, but I am not sure that my constructor values are set correctly. Can you see that from the `topics` field?

When I then call `contractObject.at("0xe23cfc0248b83a4bce8f9701a86e08e9cf9c59f4").totalSupply();`, it returns 0. But it should return 1000000.

Comment: You're missing `await` in that last line of code (or some other means of handling the `Promise` object returned from the call to `totalSupply`).

Comment: And yes, I can see it in your topics: `topics[2] == 0xf4240 == 1000000`.

Comment: BTW, your code implies that you're still on web3.js v0.x. It might be a good time to switch to v1.x (I'd recommend v1.2.1). Just beware that there are several API-breaking changes.

Comment: Yeah. I built this in 2017 and last looked at it in 2018.
`dep.admin().then(console.log);` gives me
`TypeError: 'then' is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1`
and `await dep.admin();`
`(anonymous): Line 1:7 Unexpected identifier (and 1 more errors)`

Comment: But it seems that the constructor is called correctly, right? So that just means that I am making a mistake when I call the methods on the contract.

Comment: I also tried
--
> `dep.balanceOf(eth.accounts[0], function(err, balance){console.log(balance)});`
`0`
`undefined`
and
`dep.admin.call();` returns "0x" as if the admin field is not set.

Answer (score 1):

Following my comments above, try this:

```
async function test() {
    var contractObject = web3.eth.contract(...);
    var submittedContract = await contractObject.new(...);
    var totalSupply = await contractObject.at(...).totalSupply();
    console.log(totalSupply);
}

test();
```

Comment: When I call `await` in front of anything I get "unexpected identifier". Calling `web3.version` from the geth terminal returns 'api: "0.20.1"'. Should or can I upgrade web3js?

Comment: From what I read here on Stack Exchange (old answer though) that is not possible: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1844/6106

Comment: @ThorkilVærge: You can only do that from inside an `async` function, as shown in the code above. Please, to start with, try this example **exactly as is** (i.e., place it in a separate file and execute that file via `node` from a command line).

Comment: Got it. I am trying this with `web3@0.20.1` now. But I don't know how to get the contract address which goes into the `at` function. `address` is undefined on the submittedContract object.

Comment: Adding a sleep(60s) such that the tx was mined and following your recipe above `totalSupply` still returns 0 and admin returns "0x".

Comment: @ThorkilVærge: Why don't you `console.log(submittedContract)` and see what's in there? BTW, I believe that web3 updates `contractObject` with the address of your contract after you deploy it, so all you really need to do is `await contractObject.totalSupply()`. But I'm not entirely sure of that.

Comment: Code run: https://pastebin.com/qSNqUPCg
Console output: https://pastebin.com/rSpqyGBa

Comment: @ThorkilVærge: No links please. If you have something to say, then post it here. Also, I didn't suggest that you printed the receipt in order for me to see it, I suggested it in order for you to search the contract address in there and find out its exact location within that object.

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot. I did find the address, it was available after I introduced the sleep such that the transaction was mined. After doing this I am back to square one: All methods calls return zero/nil.

Comment: @ThorkilVærge: As far as I know from experience, if you're using `await` then there shouldn't be any sleep period involved here. Maybe you should do `totalSupply.call()` or `totalSupply().call()` under this version of web3.js. But if that is indeed the case, then I would expect the current code of `totalSupply()` to return an object rather than 0.

Comment: You are right about totalSupply(), it returns `BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }  ` which, when printed with toString() is 0. Adding .call() gives the error "(node:893) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: submittedContract.totalSupply(...).call is not a function"

Comment: @ThorkilVærge: I meant an object which represents a web3-function-call. That one is an object which represent a big number whose integer value is indeed 0, so I'm not sure what else you could be doing wrong I'm afraid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101811/discussion-between-thorkil-vaerge-and-goodvibration).

Comment: Adding `--dev` when launching geth resolved my issue. I don't understand why. For more information, see:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/20427

Comment: IMO it should be `await submittedContract.totalSupply.call()`

Comment: @GabrielG.: I wrote this here in one of the comment above. He/she tried it, and that didn't resolve the problem.